# Decomposition of 3D rotation (in analogy to translation)

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, linear-algebra

Any displacement along a line can be written as the sum of two perpendicular displacements, which then form a closed triangle with the total displacement vector.

My question is: Can something similar be done with rotation?

Consider a rotation about a fixed axis. Can this always be decomposed into two rotations about two perpendicular axes, which again form a triangle (or similar) with the total axis of rotation? In other words, if the axis of rotation is inclined such that it has components in $x$ and $y$ with respect to a global coordinate system, will the rotation it permits never involve a rotation about the $z$-axis?

If it is indeed possible to consider rotations in this way, what is the simplest way to decompose the rotation into fractional contributions from these two putative axes?

EDIT (in response to comment):

A "sharpened" version of my "theorem" may read as: Any rotation about a fixed arbitrary axis can be decomposed into a rotation about three orthogonal axes, but not into a rotation about two orthogonal axes."

From the (very helpful) first reply, I surmise this is correct?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607486/eulers-angles-to-axis-angle-conversion). Be mindful you need ***three*** , not two, Euler angles.

Comment: The wording of your "never involve"  proposed theorem is worded ambiguously. Can you sharpen it as a "true or false" such? The axis of rotation of any great circle on the globe can be arrived at by unique longitude and latitude rotations.

Comment: @CosmasZachos do we need three angles for *rotation about a fixed axis*?

Comment: @Roger Vadim. Of course not. What's taking you there to ask that? Who would *ever* ask that?

Comment: @CosmasZachos the OP in their third paragraph.

Comment: No he is not! *That's  why* I asked him to parse out his "theorem"... What could you imagine my point to be? He obviously needs to review the [Gibbs composition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rodrigues_vector).

Comment: What do you mean by rotations? Becasue for infinitesimal rotations, or for rotational speeds **yes** you can decompose the vector into two components, but for finite rotations the answer is not exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably asking about the [Gibbs composition of rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rodrigues_vector) (1884), an idiosyncratic non-abelian law. If you describe a rotation by a Gibbs vector
$$ \mathbf{g} = \hat{\mathbf{e}}\tan\frac{\theta}{2},$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{e}}$ is the unit direction of the rotation and $\theta$ the rotation angle, then the Gibbs vector of two such successive rotations
**g** and **f** is
$$(\mathbf{g},\mathbf{f}) = \frac{\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{f}-\mathbf{f}\times\mathbf{g}}{1-\mathbf{g}\cdot\mathbf{f}} \,. 
$$

So, if these vectors are in the x- and y- directions, the composed rotation will necessarily have a component in the z- direction as well. Do you see this, regardless of which constituent rotation goes first?

The elementary su(2) composition law is normally taught like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#The_group_composition_law_of_SU(2)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a rotation can be decomposed into several successive rotations (3 in usual 3-dimensional space) using, e.g., [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). The catch is that these successive rotations are do not commute with each other, i.e., the order in which they are done matters.